# Eigenvector centrality in a directed linear network

Tags: linear-algebra, network

Here is an example I wanted to use to illustrate the problems of eigenvector centralities in directed networks. The network has 3 nodes and two edges. $$A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C.$$

Without stongly connected component, I expected the eigencentralities to be all zero. Matlab however tells me otherwise. Now I am not sure if I am making a mistake or if this is a numerical issue. All eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix are zero.

The Matlab program I use is

```
C = [ 
0 1 0  
0 0 1  
0 0 0  ];

CT = C' % Taking the inverse to consider incoming edges.

[V D] = eig(CT);
diagD = diag(D);
maxeigenvalue = max(diagD);
[M,I] = max(diagD);
LeftEigencentrality = abs(V(:,I))
```

Comment: $ C^3 = 0 $ for your matrix C
Correct form for an appropriate matrix is

$$ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-a_{1} & b_{1} & 0\\
0 & -a_{2} & b_{2}\\
0 & 0 & -a_{3}
\end{array}\right) $$

Comment: Thanks @Mamut. Could you explain your comment? Are we using the same definition of eigenvector centrality? I am following for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvector_centrality

Comment: For a network 
$$A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C.$$
a part $A\rightarrow B $ means that if B increase in the same moment, A decrease, with some coefficient.  Ditto  $B\rightarrow C$ . So, diagonal elements of the matrix should not be zero.
This is hint only, a correct form depends on 

* constants = rapidity of reactions  $A\rightarrow B $ and  $B\rightarrow C $

* meaning of symbolic entry $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$ For instance, if this is short form for ODE system

Comment: $$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}\right)=C\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}\right) $$

Comment: It seems the terminology is not standardized. The definition of eigenvector centrality you're using seems to be what in sociology is called Katz or Bonacich centrality. There, the diagonal is not zero.